# How p-value is calculated in random forest when using measure_importance?

Tags: r, random-forest, importance

I am using random forest for importance analysis of my variables. I use measure_importance() and at the last column, p values are given. I used R. I used randomForest() and RandomForestExplainer() packages.
1. I am confused how they were calculated.
2. Should I think the variables with high p values (i.e. p>0.05) are not significant so  should i omit them? I also added my result.

Thanks in advance

[image: my result]

Comment: There are different ways of calculating these p-values and without you telling us which software / settings you are using it is unlikely that you'll receive a satisfying answer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write the software.  I use R. I use randomForest() and RandomForestExplainer() packages.